# What is the appropriate way to find linearly independent column vectors in a square matrix?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I want to find linearly independent column vectors in a square matrix, but without using sympy. The reason why I don't want to use a sympy is that it is very slow in cases of calculation of large matrices.

For example,

```py
matrix = [[2, 3 ,5],[-1, -4, -10],[1, -2, -8]]

_, ind_col_idx = sympy.Matrix(matrix.T).rref()

print(ind_col_idx) # (0,1)

print(matrix[ind_col_idx,:]) #array([[  2,   3,   5], [ -1,  -4, -10]])
```

In similar Stack Overflow questions, to find linearly independent columns in a square matrix, the recommended method is to use eigenvalue. If eigenvalue is zero, its corresponding eigenvector is linearly dependent. But I don't understand the relationship between eigenvalue and linear independence.

Can you explain the relationship between eigenvalue and independence?
Plus, determining linearly independent columns using eigenvalue is not correct.

```py
matrix = [[2, 3 ,5],[-1, -4, -10],[1, -2, -8]])

lambdas, V =  np.linalg.eig(matrix) # [-1.12449980e+01,  1.24499800e+00, -1.54101807e-15], []

ind_col_idx = np.where(lambdas == 0)[0] # []
```

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com